# Specify parquet file size when using Apache Beam

Tags: java, hadoop, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, parquet

I'm trying to extend Google's Dataflow template to move data from BQ to parquet files on Cloud Storage, and I'm blocked trying to control parquet file sizes.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/bigquery-to-parquet

I'm running the pipeline locally using Direct runner, and it works fine but I'm not able to control the size of the parquet files. The main target is to ensure a file size of 1GB that is the recommended size.

Some facts and tests I did:

- I can control the number of shards using .withNumShards(xxx) that impact directly on the amount of files generated in the output folder, because this is related to the parallelism in the pipeline, if I set 1 shard I have only 1 file with all the data, if I set 5 shards I get 5 parquet files, and if I use the default the amount of parquet files will depend on how many shards are assigned to the pipeline.
- There's a .withRowGroupSize() configuration but it's only to modify how data is stored in the parquet file, it doesn't impact on the final size directly.
- I found a FixedWindows configuration, but it's a time-based configuration, so it's not deterministic for the file size.
- I also was trying to use the page size configuration, but it's not directly available in the version I'm using (Apache beam 2.46.0, including all the sdk and runners dependencies)

I'm running out of ideas, and couldn't find information related to this issue.  So I would like to understand if this is a common practice considering there's a recommended file size for Parquet, and if someone can provide more info about how to achieve this.

A short version of the code (not completed, but it's basically based on the template mentioned above)

```
        TypedRead<GenericRecord> readFromBQ =
            BigQueryIO.read(SchemaAndRecord::getRecord)
                .from(options.getTableRef())
                .withTemplateCompatibility()
                .withMethod(Method.DIRECT_READ)
                .withCoder(AvroCoder.of(schema));

        /*
         * Steps: 1) Read records from BigQuery via BigQueryIO.
         *        2) Write records to Google Cloud Storage in Parquet format.
         */
        pipeline
            /*
             * Step 1: Read records via BigQueryIO using supplied schema as a PCollection of
             *         {@link GenericRecord}.
             */
            .apply("ReadFromBigQuery", readFromBQ)
            /*
             * Step 2: Write records to Google Cloud Storage as one or more Parquet files
             *         via {@link ParquetIO}.
             */
            .apply(
                "WriteToParquet",
                FileIO.<GenericRecord>write()
                    .via(
                        ParquetIO.sink(schema))
                    .to("/my/path/to/local/bucket")
//                    .withNumShards(1)
                    .withSuffix(FILE_SUFFIX));

        // Execute the pipeline and return the result.
        return pipeline.run();
```

Thanks